# Scraping Trophy Data from The Official Playstation Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, phantomjs

Im trying to use PhantomJS to scrape the trophy data from http://my.playstation.com/logged-in/trophies/public-trophies/

The page requires you enter a valid username and then click 'go' and the page will load the data. Ive gotten this to work somewhat, but it never loads the trophy data into the div. Im hoping im missing something ajax related thats causing this?

```
  var fullpagehtml = page.evaluate(function() 
  {
        document.getElementById("trophiesId").value = "<<valid user id>>";
        //checkPTrophies(); btn click calls this function
        $('#btn_publictrophy').click().delay( 6000 );

        console.log("\nWaiting for trophy list to load...");
        var trophylist = document.getElementById("trophyTrophyList").innerHtml; // all the data i want ends up inside this div
        var counter = 0; //delay andset timeout wont work here so this is the best i coukld think of
        while (trophylist == null)
        {
            //presumably the ajax query should kick in on the page and populate this div, but it doesnt.
            trophylist = document.getElementById("trophyTrophyList").innerHtml;
            counter ++;
            if(counter == 1000000)
            {
                console.log($('#trophyTrophyList').html());
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
        return document.all[0].outerHTML;

  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `delay( 6000 )` does absolutely nothing as the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) says:

> The `.delay()` method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—`.delay()` is not a replacement for JavaScript's native `setTimeout` function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

To wait you have to do this outside of the page context (busy waiting doesn't work in JavaScript because it is single threaded):

```
page.evaluate(function() {
    document.getElementById("trophiesId").value = "<<valid user id>>";
    //checkPTrophies(); btn click calls this function
    $('#btn_publictrophy').click();
});

console.log("\nWaiting for trophy list to load...");
setTimeout(function(){
    var fullpagehtml = page.evaluate(function() {
        var trophylist = document.getElementById("trophyTrophyList").innerHTML;
        return trophylist;
    });
}, 20000);
```

You also might want to use [`waitFor`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) to wait until `#trophyTrophyList` is populated instead of using `setTimeout`:

```
waitFor(function(){
    return page.evaluate(function(){
        var e = document.getElementById("trophyTrophyList");
        return e && e.innerHTML;
    });
}, function(){
    // TODO: get trophies
});
```

This won't get you far, because just because `#trophyTrophyList` is loaded, doesn't mean that the descendent elements are already in the DOM. You have to find some selector which signalizes that the page is sufficiently loaded for example by waiting until a `.trophy-image` exists in the page. It works for me with a 20 second timeout of the `waitFor` function.

```
waitFor(function(){
    return page.evaluate(function(){
        var e = document.querySelector("#trophyTrophyList .trophy-image");
        return e;
    });
}, function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var trophiesDiv = page.evaluate(function(){
            return document.getElementById("trophyTrophyList").innerHTML;
        });
        console.log(trophiesDiv);
    }, 1000); // wait a little longer
}, 20000);
```

Don't forget that you need `page.evaluate` to actually access the DOM. Btw, it is `innerHTML` not `innerHtml`.